# Are questions about Mendeley on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've answered two questions about Mendeley recently: [How to cite in LaTeX using Mendeley?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180059/32374) and [Changing cite name in .bib files generated from Mendeley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173032/32374). I think they might be off-topic, but I can't decide.

These two questions are about Mendeley functionality specifically, rather than some other Mendeley questions on the Exchange that were about using Mendeley's `.bib` output (which I would judge to be more on-topic, since they're mostly related to BibTeX rather than Mendeley specifically). Examples of what I would consider definitely on-topic questions are:

- [Warning Undefined citation from bibtex (export from Mendeley)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166469/32374)
- [Citations in Texmaker using Mendeley to form a bibtex database](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153130/32374)
- [How to convert .bib generated by Mendeley for use with amsrefs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12511/32374)

Are questions like the two quoted at the top on-topic for TeX.SX?

Answer (score 7):

I think the first question is on-topic, since it is about how to use Mendeley's output in LaTeX, whereas the second question is off-topic, since it is about how to adjust Mendeley's output.